# butterknife zelezny can't show in generate menu for AndroidStudio1.3.1

Tags: butterknife

My Android studio version is 1.3.1,
When I add the plugin of butterknife zelezny 1.3.2 by the step:
download it and install via Preferences → Plugins → Install plugin from disk.

but, failed to show the button of "Generate ButterKnife Injections" in the menu of generate.

what's reason of this issue? How can resolve it?
Thanks.

Comment: It'd be better to ask on http://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Maybe your butterknife version is too high that the butterknife zelezny does not support

Answer (score 7):

1. restart your AS
2. right click on R.layout.my_layout
3. choose generate(or click Alt+Insert)
4. you may see "generate Butterknife injections" item in the menu

Answer (score 7):

I also faced the same .So if am correct you have not added butter knife dependencies in your gradle file.

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
}
```

Add this in your projecct `build.gradle(Module:app)`

Once you are done with you will get `Generate ButterKnife Injections` option on right click of layout.

Answer (score 3):

as @Woi mentioned from above you can do this way.

For Windows you can do the same by following below steps.

1.right click on `R.layout.my_layout` in activity or fragment

2.Click generate(Alt+Inser)

3.Generate butterknife injection(Ctrl+Shift+B)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It works on 7.0.1. Not works on 8.0.1

1.works:

```
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
```

2.not works:

```
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.0.1'
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue but restarting didn't fix it. I resolved it by adding `classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:8.7.0'` to my gradle build file at project level so that it's buildscript section looks like

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        ...
        classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:8.7.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

Secondly, to see the "Generate ButterKnife Injections" in the menu, you'll need to  focus the mouse cursor on the layout file and right-click on it then select "Generate".

e.g. in Fragment, `View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_create_new_order, container, false);` right click on "fragment_create_new_order" and select "Generate"

Answer (score 1):

My Android studio version is 3.1.2, When I add the plugin of butterknife zelezny 1.6.0 by the step: download it and install via **Preferences → Plugins → Browse repositories** and search for ButterKnife Zelezny.

I had this same issue.
I resolved it by adding classpath **'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:8.8.1'** to my gradle build file at project level so that it's buildscript section looks like:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:8.8.1'
    }
}
```

https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife README.md is uesful.