# android studio 3.0.1 Unable to use plug-in ButterKnifeZelezny

Tags: android, butterknife

when Right click on usage of desired layout reference (e.g. R.layout.main in my Activity or Fragment), then Not appearance Generate and Generate ButterKnife Injections !

My config

```
 compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.6.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.6.0'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [butterknife zelezny can't show in generate menu for AndroidStudio1.3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32252111/butterknife-zelezny-cant-show-in-generate-menu-for-androidstudio1-3-1)

Answer (score 0):

For Windows you can do this way

1.right click on R.layout.my_layout in activity or fragment

2.Click generate(Alt+Inser)

3.Generate butterknife injection(Ctrl+Shift+B)

[image]